# Any way to achieve coalesce row wise?

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I have a table

```
| ID  |  V1  |  V2   |   
| 100 |  1   |  1    |
| 100 | null |  1    |
| 101 | null |  null |
| 101 |  1   |  1    |
| 102 |  1   |  null |
| 102 |  1   |  null |
```

Needed Sample output:

ID 100 has V1 value in at least one of the rows so need 1

same for ID 101 has V1 value in at least one of the rows so need 1

ID 102 has no V2 value in both rows so need null

Required output

```
| ID  |  V1  |  V2   |
| 100 |  1   |  1    |
| 101 |  1   |  1    |
| 102 |  1   |  null |
```

tried to combine the values into a list and get the max value

Is there any easier function which can achieve this?

Comment: What if your ID 102 has 1 and 2 as V1 value, which one do you need?

Comment: Why not `max()` and GROUP BY? That seems pretty easy to me.

Comment: It will never be like that v1 and v2 will have values only 1 and null

Comment: @JNevill yes it will work, I wanted to know if there is any function for that

Comment: There isn't only because there is no guarantee that you can grant to the database that every row for that column is going to have a null or some exact same value. Like there is no way to say "If every value you encounter in this column is either nothing or some single distinct value, then print out the single distinct value for this group by list". Instead you pick an aggregate formula that matches your requirements and use that. In this case you can go with `max`, `min`, or `avg` because it doesn't matter.

Comment: Speaking more about that "Guarantee" it would essentially be a column constraint, but that really doesn't exist except for maybe an ENUM type in mysql that only has a single value in it. Conversely there is no aggregate function that is only made usable when a specific constraint is used, which is primarily what you are asking for here. Like `SELECT THE_NON_NULL_VALUE_IF_SINGLE_ENUM(mycolumn), id FROM yourtable GROUP BY ID;` What would happen if your column being aggregated here had the values `1`, `2`,`5`, `zebra` in it... `Max()`, `Min()`, `GROUP_CONCAT` etc. all give you non-error results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select ID, max(V1) as V1, max(V2) as V2 from table group by ID;
```

Comment: Yes this work wanted to know if there is a function like coalesce which does col wise for rows

Comment: @SantoshSantu such function is an aggregation or analytic. min, max, collect_set, avg, etc, etc

Answer (score 1):

You can do aggregation :

```
select id, max(v1) as v1, max(v2) as v2
from table t
group by id;
```

Comment: Yes this work wanted to know if there is a function like coalesce which does col wise for rows